# Is it appropriate for me to ask for a salary review although they did that last year?

Tags: salary, ethics, salary-review

I'm new in the tech world (2 years of experience). In earlier jobs, there was no possibility of a salary review but in my current company, it is possible to receive a raise.

I don't know if it's too early to ask for that because they gave me a review and a raise last year. I don't even know if it's appropriate for me to ask cause I don't know if they really have a policy of an annual review or the earlier raise was just an extraordinary thing.

My development in these two years was good, I delivered all tasks assigned on time and received good comments in all of the code reviews. For context, the company is based in southern Europe.

My question is: it's appropriate for me to ask for a review this year? or should I just wait for them to give me a new one?

Comment: Are you asking if waiting two years is long enough to ask for an annual review?  If you have been there for two years, wouldn’t you have already had at least one annual review, with another review either due very soon or was recently accomplished?

Comment: I had a review last year, i ask if it's appropiate for me to ask for a review this year or if i should just wait for them to give me a new one. I will edit the question and try to say that better

Comment: When last year? December, June, January?  If your company does yearly annual reviews, you can ask for a review, every year.  If it’s been a month since your last review, I wouldn’t ask for a review, it hasn’t been a year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should get this cleared first if they have an **annual performance review** or not. You should contact the HR of the company to get clarity on the same.

> it's appropiate for me to ask for a review this year?

Yes, absolutely yes! If you're working so hard and if the company has a review policy then why not? Why not ask for what you deserve?

> or should i just wait for them to give me a new one?

Most companies have a fixed cycle for annual reviews. After confirming if they have an existing policy, you should wait for at least 12 months before expecting a raise.

---

Now assuming they don't have a policy yet, I would suggest you to wait for a full 12 months after your last raise, and then set up a meeting with your boss/HR and convey your increment desire in that meeting.

Comment: I edited to remove code markdown because it causes accessibility issues (screen readers treat it differently). Hopefully the replacement formatting I used still gets across the same idea, but if not, feel free to edit it again.

Comment: "If you're working so hard and if the company has a review policy then why not? Why not ask for what you deserve?" It has been my experience that salaries are not a reward for hard work, and more a reflection on capability and need for the role. Maybe asking for a bonus would be more appropriate.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Bonus would be one time, salary increment is permanent.

Comment: @Zoinks Exactly. Why would you get an ongoing "reward" for a single years hard work? My point is, if you go into the meeting thinking you "deserve" a raise based on hard-work, it's not likely to be a good outcome. Far better to go into that meeting and show how capability has improved.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Annual appraisals are also reward for past year hard work... Why shouldn't one get them?

Comment: Sure. But a company is not likely to give you a salary bump because you worked hard. And if they did, they don't really know what they are doing. As I said, it doesn't make sense to give a salary increase for hard work. In the employee eliminates discretionary effort in the next year, do they also get a pay cut?

Comment: @GregoryCurrie I guess that's why managers are there to make sure that doesn't happen. Or if it does then it won't be good for the employee...

Comment: That doesn't make sense in the context of discretionary effort (where the employee isn't compelled to put in the extra effort). A salary increase makes sense if the employee is agreeing to increase their KPIs and performance on an ongoing basis. This happens on a change in capability. But this is forward-looking, not backward-looking.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**

A salary review every year (or even every 6 months at some places) is not unusual in most jobs (at least the ones I've been at).

Obviously your job doesn't have this structure, but I don't think it's unreasonable to ask for a review after 12 months since your last.

Just set up a meeting with your boss and discuss all your achievements over the last 12 months (ensure you have good examples to back you up). If you have objectives in the company - even better! You can say how you have met your objectives. If not, I'd suggest asking for some, both short and long term. They may not give you a raise, but that's fine too. In a lot of places you don't get if you don't ask, but asking what targets/objectives you need to hit in, say, 6 months in order to be considered for one is a good course of action in that case.